# Do I need the installer first before texlive install?

Tags: 16.04, texlive

I want to execute `apt-get install texlive-full` but
do I need to do anything before this like install an installer or anything?

Comment: apt-get IS the installer.

Answer (score 3):

## No

```
sudo apt install texlive-full
```

That command will download and install the program called `texlive-full`.

This is the command line method of installing programs in Ubuntu.

For more on how to install applications/software/programs in Ubuntu see:

[How do I install applications in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307280/how-do-i-install-applications-in-ubuntu)

Hope this helps